# Set width and height for image random by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, random

Something hard to understand for me that, how can I set width and height for the random images when they displayed. Can anyone help me, please?

This is my code

```js
    function randomImage(){
        var imagesArray = ['images/person1.jpg', 'images/person2.jpg', 'images/person3.jpg'];
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <title>Display random image</title>
        </head>

        <body>
           <input type="button" id="randomImage" onclick="randomImage()" value="Random">
           <img src="" name="canvas" />
        </body>
      </html>
```

And I do not know how to set width and height so I did not write code for this yet, this code just display images random when I click button

Your help is my pleasure

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0].src = imagesArray[num];`
and for width / height:
`document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0].style.width = "100px";`
`document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0].style.height= "100px";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify your image by name attribute, use [getElementsByName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) or the newer [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and for setting width and height you can use style attribute:

```
document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0].src = imagesArray[num];
```

or

```
document.querySelector("img[name=canvas]").src = imagesArray[num];
```

and for width and height (you can also use querySelector here):

```
document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0].style.width = "100px";      
document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0].style.height= "100px";
```

```js
function randomImage(){
  let imagesArray = ['images/person1.jpg', 'images/person2.jpg', 'images/person3.jpg'];
  let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  let image = document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0];
  image.src = imagesArray[num];
  image.style.width = "100px";
  image.style.height = "100px";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="randomImage" onclick="randomImage()" value="Random">
<img src="" name="canvas" />
```

if you want a random value for width and height, use it instead of the 100 in my sample

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class: "image"

and in CSS you should add:
.image{
width: 220px; // you put your value here
height: auto; // to considere the proportions of the image
}

I am notsure if this answers your question, but you can also choose other approach you can do as following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img>
</div>
```

where .wrapper has overflow set to hidden and img has width of 100% and height auto,

Answer (score 0):

You could've used `window.canvas` here, but that's [not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables). To retrieve one element, `document.querySelector` is your friend.

```js
randomImage();

document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  if (evt.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    randomImage();
  }
});

function randomImage() {
  const imagesArray = [
    'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
    'https://picsum.photos/300/400',
    'https://picsum.photos/100/100'
  ];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  document.querySelector("img[name='canvas']").src = imagesArray[randomNumber];

}
```

```css
button {
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 30vw;
  top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<img name="canvas" src="" />
<br><button>Another picture</button>
```